# How to structure typescript files and types

Tags: typescript

I'm just getting going with Typescript (using it with vuex in vue.js).
I'm writing a store, which is composed of modules.
Each module has a class and an associated interface for the state of that module.
For instance, the root state is

```
// store/types.ts
export interface RootState {
  user: object | null
  version: string
}
```

In another source file (`store/store.ts`), I want to refer to that interface like this:

```
export const foo: RootState = {...}
```

I tried `import {RootState} from '@/store/types.ts'` but tsc says "Cannot find module '@store/types". I tried `/// <reference types="@store/types">` but that doesn't seem to actually import the `RootState` name: I still get "Cannot find name 'RootState'.

I should say, I'm an old C/C++ programmer and I'm thinking about types.ts like a "header file" -- that may be completely wrong in a typescript world. How should I structure these files and imports so I can refer to that interface both from store/store.ts and other typescript source files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, duh. I was doing it right, almost. It's just that `import @/...` syntax doesn't seem to work in my project. `import ../file` works fine.